# Odd or even number of backslashes and escaped character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a little problem with the following code.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"((?:^|[^\\@]|\\.)+)@")

for text in [
    r"ok@\@.py",
    r"ok@\\@.py",
    r"ok@\\\@.py",
    r"ok@\\\\@.py",
    r"ok@\\\\\@.py",
]:
    search = re.search(pattern, text)
    print('---', text, sep="\n")

    if search:
        print(pattern.sub(r"\1<star>", text))

    else:
        print('<< NOTHING FOUND ! >>')
```

This prints :

```
---
ok@\@.py
ok<star>\@.py
---
ok@\\@.py
ok<star>\\<star>.py
---
ok@\\\@.py
ok<star>\\\<star>.py
---
ok@\\\\@.py
ok<star>\\\\<star>.py
---
ok@\\\\\@.py
ok<star>\\\\\<star>.py
```

The problem starts with the 3rd output that is wrong because there is first an escaped backslash and then the escaped character @. The problem continues with more backslashes : just see the last output with two escaped backslashes and then the escaped character @..

**Here is the expected output where the @ is indeed escaped only when there is an odd number of \ before it.**

```
---
ok@\@.py
ok<star>\@.py
---
ok@\\@.py
ok<star>\\<star>.py
---
ok@\\\@.py
ok<star>\\\@.py
---
ok@\\\\@.py
ok<star>\\\\<star>.py
---
ok@\\\\\@.py
ok<star>\\\\\@.py
```

What is wrong in my regex and how to fix it ?

Comment: You haven't told us the expected behaviour. How are we going to fix it if we don't know what it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)@")
```

And replace with just `<star>`

Output:

```
ok<star>\@.py 
ok<star>\\<star>.py
ok<star>\\\@.py
ok<star>\\\\<star>.py
ok<star>\\\\\@.py
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hG3hL2/2)

Comment: Indeed, the output changes regarding if there is an even or odd number of backslashes.

Comment: I have updated my question that says fisrst, but I was not very clear, that the @ is escaped only when there is an odd number of \ before it.

Comment: Cool ! But what about `pattern = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)@")` ?

Comment: Yeah.. thats redundant.. removed it.. :)